# MySQL error: Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 8

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code:

```
if ($user) {
        $highscore = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT Score FROM HighScore WHERE fbID = $user"),0);
        if (empty($highscore)) { //if no result
            echo '<div id="uhs">0</div>';
        } else { 
            echo '<div id="uhs">'. $highscore .'</div>';
        }
    } else {
        echo '<div id="uhs">0</div>';
    }
```

When I get no result from the db (because there is no `Score`), it should echo: `echo '<div id="uhs">0</div>';` but it doesn't. Instead I get the error: `MySQL error: Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 8`. I thought using: `if (empty($highscore))` should take care of it when having no result.

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it, it works fine when there is a Score in the db

Many thanks

Comment: Look here for correct usage of empty() http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `mysql_num_rows()` is used to check if `mysql_query` returned any result.

```
$highscore = mysql_query("SELECT Score FROM HighScore WHERE fbID = $user");
if (mysql_num_rows($highscore) == 0) { 
    // No result
} else {
    // Show result
}
```

Comment: Please explain _why_ the OP should "do this".  Code without an explanation is of little help to the poster or SO at large.

Comment: @Michael, yes sir, in a minute.

Answer (score 3):

For checking for empty sql results, try

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) { ... }
```

Even if no results are returned, $highscore will still be populated as an empty result set. Ergo, "empty($highscore)" will not work how you want it to.

Edit: For future use, please use [mysqli_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) instead!

Comment: Thanks, I thought combining al of it would work with empty, but after testing it failed. Got it fixed now